# Looking for a orchestration tool similar to docker-compose, but that runs ordinary processes

Tags: open-source

I'm looking for a tool, that could run processes (not containers, without virtualization) in the same fashion as if I would run them in the terminal, except with the ability to put some processes to the background and attach to them later

---

For example:

having a configuration file like

```
process1:
  command: echo "process1"

process2:
  command: echo "process2"

process3:
  command: echo "process3"
```

`tool up` - would run all 3 processes like, as written in configuration file configuration.yml

```
[process1]: process1
[process2]: process2
[process3]: process3
```

`tool down` - would stop all 3 processes (if they are still running)

`tool run process1` - would just run `process1`
`tool run process3` - would run `process1` and `process2` in background, and `process3` in foreground

`tool attach process1` - would attach to `process1` (if it is still running)

`tool log process1` - would show output of `process1` till this moment

`tool restart process1` - would restart of `process1`

`tool ps` - would show list of currently running processes

---

N.B. tools that are almost what I need, but not exaclty:

1. tmuxinator - can't put panes in background, attach to them
2. ts, task spool - can't attach to processes
3. https://www.npmjs.com/package/concurrently - doesnt have ability to run in background and attach

---

N.B. this question is copy of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57225817/how-to-orchestrate-processes-in-same-fashion-as-docker-compose-does

Comment: Hi there, did you ever find something like this?

Comment: no, actually, I was thinking about implementing something like this, but then forgot. One should look how tmux puts processes in background to implement something similar

Comment: I realized that you can basically do this using pm2 : https://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/pm2-doc-single-page/

Comment: I can put in background, it will write app output so some file, then attach, it will show all output so far and allow to enter to stdin again?

Comment: Haven't tested all of that, but I think so.